# More records will make the querying slower in mongoDB using java?

Tags: mongodb, performance, size, sql-delete

I use mongoDB for my application which has huge number of data(206k) averages 10mb size of each record.

Opening the collection in mongoCompass itself take a lot of time to load.

My queries written in java to update/get any particular record also takes time.

Indexes are present on the fields being queried on.

Deleting the unused records and reducing number of total records will help ?
If yes, I will write a job to clean up old records regularly .

Comment: Any database needs appropriate indexes created in order to scale well. Indexes are created _for queries_ though, so we can't advise on what indexes you may need without further information about the queries you are running

Comment: @user20042973 ,  Indexes are present and queries are made on the indexed fields, queies made like getById/getBysomeFiled, upsert operation etc

Comment: So then the general answer to your question is : no, adding more records will not noticeably slow down queries when appropriate indexes are present